# configure aspectLibraries for plexus-compiler-aspectj

Tags: maven-3, aspectj, maven-compiler-plugin

I've got a pretty strait forward compiler plugin configuration:

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerId>aspectj</compilerId>
            </configuration>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.plexus</groupId>
                    <artifactId>plexus-compiler-aspectj</artifactId>
                    <version>2.2</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
                    <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
                    <version>1.7.1</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

But I can't seem to figure out how to set the equivalent of the aspectj-plugins aspectLibrary configuration option.  Does such a thing exist?